# Finding the satisfied conditional clause in Java

Tags: java

I'm debugging a piece of code and I have a question: if I have a long `if` condition with multiple conditional statements bundled using `OR` or `AND`, would there be a way to find out which conditional (which all conditionals) of the `if` condition is (were) satisfied.

Comment: Can you give us an example with code? It may help clarify your question.

Comment: Why not evaluate each of those expressions with your debugger ?

Comment: Assign each condition to boolean variable and then check boolean values inside your if/else blocks so that you can check value of each condition.

Comment: Parenthesis help the person reading the long IF condition.  Add them.

Answer (score 3):

To check this you need debug your application. From Debugging you can inspect it easily by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Set the breakpoint in your code to debug the application.

Read this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/) to understand how to debug appl

Answer (score 2):

if you are working with Eclipse, put a breakpoint in the if statement line, and when the debugger stops on it, you can inspect each condition by selecting it and pressing "Ctrl+Shift+I" , a popup would show the result of the condition. You can evaluate the whole if statement or any variable in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to put a breakpoint before the `if` condition and check the values of the conditions by yourself.

If it helps you, you can change something like

```
if(myVar == 4 && myVar2 == 6)
{
    ...
}
```

to

```
if(myVar == 4)
{
    if(myVar2 == 6)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and step through that with your debugger.

Comment: What would you do with "or" condition?

Comment: I'd just put a breakpoint on the `if` statement and checking the values yourself. A great debugging technique is to write down the expected values (what you think they should be) and what they actually are for each step in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable for each condition in the if, and in the if, put all these booleans.

Then you can log all this booleans, or debug it with Eclipse.

For example, if you have:

```
if( a==b && k!=9 && i.isEmpty()) {
```

You can do:

```
boolean b1= a==b;
boolean b2 = k!=9;
boolean b3 = i.isEmpty();

logger.log(b1);
logger.log(b2);
logger.log(b3);

if (b1 && b3 && b3){
```